# Quantikz: add text without

Tags: quantikz

I have the following circuit, made using quantikz.

I was wondering how I could simply get rid of the lines between the letters on the top row.

[image]

The latex is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
a & b & c & d & e \\
& \gate{X} & \ctrl{1} & & \\
&  & \targ{}\wire[u]{q} & \gate{Z}&\\
&  & \gate{X} & &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\wireoverride{n}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}

\begin{quantikz}
    a &\wireoverride{n}b & \wireoverride{n}c & \wireoverride{n}d & \wireoverride{n}e \\
    & \gate{X} & \ctrl{1} & & \\
    &  & \targ{}\wire[u]{q} & \gate{Z}&\\
    &  & \gate{X} & &
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks. Any particular reason for the "n" in the brackets? Asking out of curiostiy.